# TypeORM and Express middleware

Tags: express, typeorm

Is there any way to bootstrap `app.use()` middleware after `createConnection()` will estabilish one?

According to `typeorm` documentation found [here](https://typeorm.io/#/example-with-express) I should use only `app.get()` or `app.post()` because they are bootstraped afterwards.

The question comes how I should handle it when I want to use middleware? In mind of splitting huge block code from one file which contains `createConnection().then(_ => dothings())` to smaller parts.

If I will try to `getRepository()` sooner in middleware than it is really created it will throw exception that `Connection "default" was not found.`

The only thing that comes into my mind is to set a some sort of flag but I belive that is not the best solution.

The most accurate question which fits mine is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663956/get-connection-after-bootstraping-in-express-js) but really there is no other solution than huge block of code?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your routes over a class and instantiate this only after the createConnection end may work.

```
app.use(new Routes().routes)
```